# Is mv atomic on my fs?

Tags: posix, mv, move

How can I check if `mv` is atomic on my fs (ext4)?

The OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8.

In general, how can I check this? I have looked around, and didn't find if my OS is standard POSIX.

Comment: Have you tried `strace`?

Comment: Related: [Will an `unlink` or `rename` portably and atomically make a `link` fail?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313886/will-an-unlink-or-rename-portably-and-atomically-make-a-link-fail)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interestingly enough, it seems the answer may be, "It depends".

To be clear, [`mv` is specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) to

> The `mv` utility shall perform actions equivalent to the [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html)
>   function

The [rename function specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) states:

> This `rename()` function is equivalent for regular files to that
>   defined by the ISO C standard. Its inclusion here expands that
>   definition to include actions on directories and specifies behavior
>   when the new parameter names a file that already exists. **That
>   specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.**

But the latest [the ISO C specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for `rename()` states:

> **7.21.4.2 The `rename` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `rename` function causes the file whose name is the string pointed to by `old` to be henceforth known by the name
>   given by the string pointed to by `new`. The file named `old` is no
>   longer accessible by that name. If a file named by the string pointed
>   to by `new` exists prior to the call to the `rename` function, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `rename` function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails, in which case if the file existed
>   previously it is still known by its original name.

Surprisingly, note that there is no explicit requirement for atomicity.  It may be required somewhere else in the latest publicly-available C Standard, but I haven't been able to find it.  If anyone can find such a requirement, edits and comments are more than welcome.

See also [Is rename() atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054844/is-rename-atomic)

Per [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html):

> If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that
>          there is no point at which another process attempting to access
>          `newpath` will find it missing.  However, there will probably be a
>          window in which both `oldpath` and `newpath` refer to the file being
>          renamed.

The Linux man page claims the *replacement* of the file will be atomic.

*Testing* and *verifying* that atomicity might be very difficult, though, if that is how far you need to go.  You're not clear as to what you mean in your use of "How can I check if mv is atomic".  Do you want requirements/specification/documentation that it's atomic, or do you need to actually *test* it?

Note also, the above *assumes* the two operand file names are in the same file system.  I can find no standard restriction on the `mv` utility to enforce that.

Comment: I have to ensure that move is atomic.
is Testing enought to accept this? I can't tell.
Yes, I'm working on a same fs (ext4 to ext4).

Comment: POSIX doesn't guarantee atomicity either, but Linux, like most unix variants, does, for “native” filesystems such as ext4.

Comment: @Gilles The [POSIX standard states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) "This `rename()` function is equivalent for regular files to that defined by [the ISO C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). ... **That specification requires that the action of the function be atomic.**" But I can't find that atomicity requirement in the C standard.  Is it there implicitly? Is it stated somewhere else in the standard?  Because it's not explicitly in the `rename()` specification that I can see. And I quoted the entire ISO C `rename` spec.

Comment: Given that ISO C only defines the behavior of one program and not of a whole system, it would be weird for it to say anything about `rename` atomicity.

Comment: @Gilles True. But we're left with the POSIX standard saying that ISO C requires that `rename()` be atomic.  Perhaps a good language lawyer question on Stackoverflow...

Comment: I read "that specification" as referring to the previous sentence ("Its inclusion here... specifies behavior when the new parameter names a file that already exists"), which refers earlier parts of the POSIX doc ("a link named new shall remain visible to other threads throughout... and refer either to the file referred to by new or old..."). In other words, POSIX promises to implement the ISO C standard, and makes additional guarantees beyond what ISO C provides. Does that interpretation help?

Comment: @Tizianoreica I know this is an ancient post, but I just saw your comment and thought I should clarify: The actual filesystem has to be the same for the rename to be atomic. Not just the same *type* of filesystem. e.g. if you have `/` as an ext4 fs and `/tmp` as a different ext4 fs then you *cannot* atomically mv from one to the other.

Comment: I think that "rename() function" in mv manual you cited refers to the OS system call, not stdio library function.

Comment: @DavidLopez First, the strange fixation that attempts to differentiate between "system calls" and "library functions" makes absolutely no sense to me.  It's meaningless.  Unless you're directly writing assembly code, ***everything*** is a library function.  POSIX defines the interface and how it behaves, not implementation details such as "Is this characterized as 'system call' or a 'library function'".  There doesn't even have to be an actual `rename` "system call" - in fact, on most modern systems there isn't.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: thanks for the clarification. What I tried to address is the difference between the **POSIX rename()** function that `mv` manual refers to, and the **ISO C standard rename()** function which is specified independently of the OS (I mean, also for non-POSIX OS's such as WIndows).

Comment: "*Returns: The rename function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails, in which case if the file existed previously it is still known by its original name.*"

This part in the C standard implies that the operation is *atomic*. Maybe this is not the *atomicity* you expect, but this is the definition of the *atomicity* for the filesystem.

Comment: @akinomyoga No, it is not.  That definition does not address what is observable from *outside* of the calling thread.  Just because the calling thread can only see either success or a failed `rename()` that leaves the original file unchanged does not mean that an outside observer would never see something like both files existing at once, or even neither file existing, or some other combination.  So no, the part you quoted doesn't even imply file system atomicity.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, thank you for your reply! I see. You are right. Does that mean before the introduction of the thread in C11 it was *effectively* atomic *within the program*, but later it became non-atomic at all because of the threads?

Answer (score 1):

`mv` is based on `rename` system call and `rename()` is atomic. You could look at the manpage `rename(2)`.

You could find answer on [Is rename() atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054844/is-rename-atomic#7054851) on stackoverflow.

What sort of fs, did you use ?

Comment: fs is ext4 - os already specified.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the systemcalls and their atomicity, maybe `inotify-tools` can serve as a test, though I am not sure if it is a guaranteed proof of atomicity.

Open 2 shells. Watch the target directory of the move in one of them:

```
inotifywait -m target/
```

Move a file into the directory in the other:

```
mv foobar target/
```

The `inotifywait` should show only one line:

```
target/ MOVED_TO foobar
```

It seems atomic in comparison to the response to `ls target/` and `touch target/a`, which produce multiline messages like:

```
# the response to ls target/
target/ OPEN,ISDIR 
target/ ACCESS,ISDIR 
target/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR
```

**PS**

I think, at least it shows that asynchronous multiprocess cooperation on files is safe with `inotify` (practically atomic): in any case you would respond only after `inotify` gave the final signal after the operation. For example, a producer-consumer setup can be implemented easily and safely with `inotify`.