# wget -i notifying when each file finishes (for processing purposes)

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, fuser

I'd like to be able to process *multiple* files downloaded by `wget -i` immediately after they are downloaded (instead of waiting for all files in the list to finish--for the entire `wget` process to exit). The trouble is: because `wget` downloads the file in place, I cannot be sure when a file is safe to process (fully downloaded). Ideally, the principled approach is (I believe) to have `wget` initially download files into a temporary directory and then `mv` them into the actual destination directory when complete. Because the `mv` is atomic*, I can guarantee that any file present in the destination directory is completely downloaded and ready for processing.

I've been through the manpage, but can't seem to find anything to this end. My current hacky approach is to use `fuser` to see if `wget` no longer has the file open. But, this is very fragile (what if `wget` opens a file multiple times?) and I'd like to avoid it.

If there isn't a way to achieve this exactly, is there a workaround that can achieve the same effect? The files are HTML pages if that's at all relevant.

*Addendum: Apparently [`mv` may not be atomic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322074/8506) (although for my env it is), although I don't think strict atomicity is needed. The only requirement is that once a file is renamed into the destination directory it is completely downloaded (and the complete contents are immediately available at the new path).

edit: Splitting the process up into multiple `wget` commands is also not ideal because it precludes using some core features of `wget` (rate limiting, HTTP keepalive, DNS caching, etc.).

Comment: Just an option for consideration: look for the second-oldest file and process that one. All sorts of caveats (only one download at a time; your processing might create new files; the last file won't have a newer file...)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yeah that's a decent solution. However, the last file not having a newer file makes it hard to come up with a reasonable termination condition (timeout isn't great depending on file size and connection speed, `fuser` just for the last is less fragile but bad). I guess I could add a sentinel dummy file URL, but it feels like there should be a better way!

Comment: What about a construct like this : `wget [url] -O /dev/stdout | [next step of your process]`

Comment: @Httqm That could work if there was a way to distinguish between separate files. Piping loses the file name and makes it difficult (impossible?) to separate the files. Note that I'm using `wget -i` to download multiple URLs here.

Comment: @BaileyParker; it gets convoluted, but your monitoring process could look for an active `wget` process -- hopefully only the one you're interested in; or the `wget` sequence could `touch` a file at the end, which your monitoring process then knows to skip; etc.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Oh that's true. I bet with some pipes you could even communicate `wget`'s PID to the monitoring process to get the right one. This removes the ability to have a dependency between `wget` and the process though. For example you can't do `wget -i $(./monitoring-process)` and have it emit new files to download. I'm probably pushing against the limits of what I should be doing here (before I should just throw everything into a script). I'm trying to lean on `wget` as much as possible, because it does its job well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aria2c` instead:

```
aria2c --on-download-complete="/path/to/script" -i file
```

so your script can be:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Finished: $3"
```

- `$1` is the gid from aria2c.
- `$2` is the number of files.
- `$3` is the filename.

Comment: Oh, looking into this now! Does `--on-download-complete` pass the path of the downloaded file by chance?

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: That'll do it. [According to the docs](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#event-hook) `$1` is the GID (assuming this is some kind of aria specific thing and not the UNIX gid) and `$2` is the number of files (1 for http) if anyone is interested. Thanks! :)